# Function with optional positional argument

Tags: bash

With the following bash function, how can I get the function allow $2 to be optional, defaulting its value when nothing is passed for that argument ?

```
serputil ()
 {
  local opstring="$1"
  local sersel="$2"
 }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

##### Like this, using [`bash` *parameter expansion*](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Parameter-Expansion.html):

```
iserputil () {
  local opstring="$1"
  local sersel="${2:-DEFAULT}"
  echo "$opstring"
  echo "$sersel"
 }

iserputil ok
```

##### Output

```
ok
DEFAULT
```

If you run

```
iserputil ok ko
```

You will get

```
ok
ko
```